# Is it possible to use server PCIe cards/PCIe RAID controller on desktop motherboard?

Tags: hardware, pci-express

I've found myself in possession of a MSI [785GT-E63](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/785GT-E63.html) motherboard. I need to put a PCIe x8 RAID controller on it, but the x16 PCIe slot is certainly originally intended for graphics cards.

Would putting a RAID controller instead of a graphics card on there work?

Comment: Sure. It's just be a waste of an x16 slot if you have a free x8. The slot is capable of faster speeds, the card just isn't going to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to work, I put a x4 RAID card in one of x16 slots :).

Comment: you can also put a 16x in an 8x slot (4x may even work)

Comment: Really ? I didn't know that, it just will perform slower I guess ?

Comment: many midrange-lowend graphics cards only use 8x because they dont need the speed, even though they take up a full 16x slot. this is why on newer motherboards today there is a open end slot at the end of the PCIe connector.